# Calling hashmap map

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have a hashmap method which is;

```
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }
```

I have a string email and I want to get the email of the method where id=10.
How can I set the email equal to that certain String basicly;
String email = getUserDetails(email Where id=10) I know I'm way off, but you get the idea.

Comment: How do you think the extra tags and a somewhat ambiguous question will help?

Comment: `SELECT name, email, uid, created_at FROM my_table WHERE id = 10`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Answer (score 2):

```
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(int id){
  HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
  String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN + " WHERE id=" + id + ";";
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
  // Move to first row
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
      user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
      user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
      user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
      user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
  }
  cursor.close();
  db.close();
  // return user
  return user;
}
```

to use it :

```
String email = getUserDetails(10).get("email");
```

Comment: the first parameter is int, getUserDetails().get("email"); works but I get compiling errors.